# Is an update statement in T-SQL really just an Delete and Insert collectively?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, crud

Just curiosity,

Does the `update` statement `delete` and `re-insert` a row in `MS SQL Server` with the amended values?

The reason I asking is because I saw that it suggests to me that a row is `deleted` and `re-inserted` when using an `output` clause.

```
UPDATE dbo.table
SET field1= 'value'
OUTPUT DELETED.field1, INSERTED.field1
WHERE ID = 12345;
GO
```

If so, would a seperate `DELETE FROM` followed by `INSERT INTO` the same table work at more or less the same speed?

Comment: Effectively that is what is happening. But for performance it would be slightly slower. Probably not enough difference to even measure but you would be turning a single statement into two. That means twice the logging and twice the number of implicit transactions.

Comment: I would imagine DELETE followed by INSERT would only be a win if you are deleting and then inserting a large number of rows.

Comment: Check http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/8028/6171 or `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Internals`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if it was physically a delete/insert pair you could never tell. SQL Server gives you specified behavior. How SQL Server physically performs the update is irrelevant for semantics (just relevant for performance).

That said, the `DELETED` and `INSERTED` tables are specified just this way so that you can use both old and new values.

Physically, an update is performed in-place if possible. If an index must be updated and the key of that index row changes you get a delete/insert pair. Again, this is indetectable to  you.